# SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 when i make post request

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I am making a post request to an api with submit() function which is attached to a ng-click directive sending the data in JSON format, it returns this error.

It is running fine on postman so the error is on client side only.

Also the email and selectedIds variables are not empty.

[image]

Here is my controller file:

```
app.controller('categoryController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$sce', '$http', '$timeout','$window', function($scope, $rootScope, $sce, $http, $timeout, $window) {
    $scope.allCategories = {};
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://qubuk.com:8081/api/v1/alltag'
    })
        .then(function (data) {
            // console.log("DATA:" + JSON.stringify(data.data.categories[0].displayName));
            // console.log("DATA category:" + JSON.stringify(data.data.categories));
            $scope.allCategories = data.data.categories;
        });

    $scope.selectedIds = [];

    $scope.change = function(category, active){
        if(active){
            $scope.selectedIds.push(category.id);
        }else{
            $scope.selectedIds.splice($scope.selectedIds.indexOf(category.id), 1);
        }

        // console.log("SELECTED IDS:" + $scope.selectedIds);
    };

    $scope.email = "faiz.krm@gmail.com"
    console.log("email is "+  $scope.email);

    $scope.submit = function () {
        var tagsData = {"emailId": $scope.email,
                        "tagsId": $scope.selectedIds};
        console.log("tagsData:" + JSON.stringify(tagsData));
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url: 'http://qubuk.com:8081/api/v1/user/update/tags',
            data: tagsData
        })
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log("Ids sent successfully!");
                alert("successful");
                $window.location.href = '/app/#/feed';
            })
    };

    // console.log("amm Categories:" + JSON.stringify($scope.allCategories));
}]);
```

edit: the response is not a JSON object... it is a string. I do think error is due to this only... how can i resolve it on the front end...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

to your request:

```
$http({
        method:'POST',
        url: 'http://qubuk.com:8081/api/v1/user/update/tags',
        data: tagsData,
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
```

Alternately try to pass a stringify data:

```
$http({
        method:'POST',
        url: 'http://qubuk.com:8081/api/v1/user/update/tags',
        data: JSON.stringify(tagsData),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
```

Comment: no it did not work... can this error be due to the fact that the response is not in JSON... response is a string which says:  updated.

Comment: I think this because in the network panel of developer tools, it shows a successful hit to the target api...